Setting dynamic visibility in plotly with function
I would like to set a "dynamic" visibility when using plotly.
I have a bunch of data which I have grouped in a drop-down menu.
I would like to be able to select a couple of series from each drop-down menu and keep it visible while I "browse" through different menus.
Here is MRE:
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

fig = go.Figure()

for i in range(1,4):
    fig.add_trace(
                            go.Scatter3d
                            (
                                x=np.linspace(0, 1),
                                y=np.linspace(0, 1),
                                z=i*np.linspace(0, 1),
                                mode='markers',
                                name=f"g1_{i}",
                                visible = "legendonly",
                                legendgroup="" ,
                            )
                        )
    
for i in range(4,7):
    fig.add_trace(
                            go.Scatter3d
                            (
                                x=np.linspace(0, 1),
                                y=np.linspace(0, 1),
                                z=i*np.linspace(0, 1),
                                mode='markers',
                                name=f"g2_{i}",
                                visible = "legendonly",
                                legendgroup="" ,
                            )
                        )
    
for i in range(7,10):
    fig.add_trace(
                            go.Scatter3d
                            (
                                x=np.linspace(0, 1),
                                y=np.linspace(0, 1),
                                z=i*np.linspace(0, 1),
                                mode='markers',
                                name=f"g3_{i}",
                                visible = "legendonly",
                                legendgroup="" ,
                            )
                        )
    
fig.update_layout(  
        updatemenus=[
                        dict(    
                            buttons=list([
                                dict(
                                    args=[{"visible": [True if trace.visible else "legendonly" for trace in fig['data']]}],
                                    label=("All"),
                                    method="restyle",
                                ),
                                
                                 dict(args=[{"visible": ["legendonly" if ("g2" in trace.name) else False for trace in fig['data']]}],
                                    label="g2",
                                    method="restyle",
                                ),                               
                            ]),
                            direction = "down",
                            showactive=True,
                            x=0.5,
                            xanchor="center",
                            y=1.1,
                            yanchor="top"
                        )])

Is it possible to define a function (callback) when pressing the "G2" button to keep whatever was visible and just show with "legendonly" was is available in the group defined in "G2"?
Best Regards

The best approach to what you want (imo) is to use Dash, which integrates with Plotly and gives great flexibility to design layout and write callbacks to implement functionality. See link below. You might, possibly, be able to do it entirely within Plotly, but Dash is likely to make it easier and more maintainable. https://dash.plotly.com/tutorial
